# Check whether Sync Framework has already provisioned a table with __sysTrackingContext?

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

## Question

**How do we programmatically check whether the Sync Framework has already provisioned a table?** That is, how do we detected whether the table already has the __sysTrackingContext column? Here are some approaching that I am considering.

Right now I am receiving this error.

```
{"A column named '__sysTrackingContext' already belongs to this DataTable."}
```

So, I could catch that error and, in the catch block, call the `SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.SetCreateTrackingTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);` before continuing as usual.

Another alternative would be to query the table in the database, and then check whether it has the __sysTrackingContext column.

My sense, though, is that the Sync Framework has a method for this. Does it? If so, what is that method? I am looking for something like this:

`bool isProvisioned = SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.TableIsProvisioned("tblMyTable");`

## Edit: Here is how I am provisioning my tables.

```
private DbSyncScopeDescription DescribeTheScope(
    IEnumerable<string> tablesToSync, 
    string scopeName,
    SqlCeConnection conn)
{
    // create a scope description object
    var scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription { ScopeName = scopeName };

    // add each table to the scope without any filtering
    foreach (var tableDesc in tablesToSync.Select(
        tableName => 
            SqlCeSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, conn)))
    {
        scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);
    }

    return scopeDesc;
}

private void ProvisionNode(
    string scopeName, 
    string[] tablesToSync, 
    SqlCeConnection conn)
{
    var ceConfig = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(conn);
    if (!ceConfig.ScopeExists(scopeName))
    {
        DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = 
            DescribeTheScope(tablesToSync, scopeName, conn);
        ceConfig.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
        ceConfig.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
        ceConfig.Apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: the _sysTrackingContext is only valid for SQL CE databases. How are you provisioning your tables? the error occurs if that column is being added as a column to be synched (most likely via GetDescriptionForTable) and not because a table has already been added to a scope.

Comment: @JuneT I was on your website earlier when I was trying to solve this. You're right, I was using GetDescriptionForTable. I posted a code example of what I am doing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: check if you can use the SQL CE Change Tracking API directly...lookup SqlCeChangeTracking.GetTrackingOptions,that should tell you if the table is tracked or not